# React Native / Firebase - upload image with additional info

Tags: firebase, react-native

I used this block of code to select an image when button is pressed to upload to firebase.

```
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={ () => this._pickImage() }
    style={styles.button}>
    <Text
    style={styles.buttonText}>
    Select a Photo
    </Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>

    _pickImage() {
    this.setState({ uploadURL: '' })

    ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary({}, response  => {
                                   uploadImage(response.uri)
                                   .then(url => this.setState({ uploadURL: url }))
                                   .catch(error => console.log(error))
                                   });
    }// end _pickImage

const uploadImage = (uri, mime = 'application/octet-stream') => {
       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                       const uploadUri = Platform.OS === 'ios' ?              uri.replace('file://', '') : uri
                    const sessionId = new Date().getTime()
                   let uploadBlob = null
                   const imageRef = storage.ref('images').child(`${sessionId}`)

                   fs.readFile(uploadUri, 'base64')
                   .then((data) => {
                         return Blob.build(data, { type: `${mime};BASE64` })
                         })
                   .then((blob) => {
                         uploadBlob = blob
                         return imageRef.put(blob, { contentType: mime })
                         })
                   .then(() => {
                         uploadBlob.close()
                         return imageRef.getDownloadURL()
                         })
                   .then((url) => {
                         resolve(url)
                         })
                   .catch((error) => {
                          reject(error)
                          })
                   })
}
```

This works fine. How can I change this to let the user select photo and then hit another button store additional info for the image like Description entered by the user into the same data structure in firebase?